# Open dialog, slot filling chatbot

Tags: dialogflow-es

Hi I am creating slot filling chatbot where I would like to ask as much open question as possible at the beginning to make my flow the most similar to the normal conversation. 
[image]

How can I achieve such a thing in terms of intents. Should I create three separate intents for case 1,2 and 3 and adding context flows in terms of 2nd and 3rd? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a case like this, you can do them as a single simple Intent that has prompts for parameters/slots that aren't addressed by the user.

First, we'll need a simple `vehicle` Entity type. Something like this, perhaps:

[image]

Once we have that, we can create an Intent and give it a few sample phrases:

[image]

We then need to do a few additional things (which are illustrated in the picture by the two orange arrows):

1. We need to mark the parameters as **Required**.
2. We need to give some **Prompts** for each parameter

With these, the Intent won't be complete until the user has responded to each prompt to fill the parameters. Once the user has given all the required values, it will call your fulfillment.

Comment: Oki Fine that is solving my issue but another arises. I would like to ask how to place up to 10 suggestion chips within prompts (to all required parameters?) Can you suggest me how to do that cause i know that i can add suggestion chips as a general response to the intent. I would be very grateful :)

Comment: That is best asked as a separate question.

Comment: Here is my new question as a separate post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091538/slot-filling-chatbot-suggestion-chips-in-prompts