# Slot filling chatbot, suggestion chips in prompts

Tags: dialogflow-es

Hi I am creating slot filling chatbot where I would like to ask as much open question as possible at the beginning to make my flow the most similar to the normal conversation.
[image]

How can I achieve two types of prompts one general to specify which parameter is missing and if user will not fill it in a correct way then i would like to suggest him answers by using suggestion chips? (Blue on the flow diagram above)

Comment: I have never been using webhook. So would be grateful to have explained how to make it. I would love to have that feature available inside google assistant.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, your requirements can only be implemented in webhook code; the Dialogflow configuration is not enough to set up this kind of dialog. A webhook is necessary - however, some resources discourage that altogether. Go and read [The different types of Dialogflow (API.AI) slot filling tasks](https://miningbusinessdata.com/different-types-api-ai-slot-filling-tasks/) carefully.

If you decide to start using webhook for slot-filling (this [sample webhook implementation](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-weather-python/blob/master/app.py) is a good starting point), it will:

```
+----------+         +-------------+        +-------------+
|          | ------> |             | -----> |             |
|   User   |         | Dialogflow  |        |   Webhook   |
|          | <------ |             | <----- |             |
+----------+         +-------------+        +-------------+
```

1. receive a request with the recognized intent and entities
2. ask follow-up questions (either asking for a missing entity or offering a suggestion if an unsupported value was provided)

Basically, this means that Dialogflow is now used only for natural language understanding (NLU) and the webhook becomes responsible for dialog management.

Comment: OK i read through https://miningbusinessdata.com/different-types-api-ai-slot-filling-tasks/ but what i found there is discouraging a bit your approach to solve my issue. Could you help me to achieve suggestion chips inside webhook cause I have no clue how to do that? Yes I am a noobie.

Comment: Yes, it is discouraging, but the article doesn't suggest a good way of doing it. My approach is similar to the paragraph `You use webhooks for the actual slot filling` and I don't know any other one.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more precise about the help you need? You need to start with writing a dummy webhook (same answer returned every time), deploying it somewhere (Heroku worked fine for me) and configuring it in Dialogflow.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I understand, dialogflow.com has no such provision to define multiple prompts within single intent so either way to do this is to use webhooks for slot-filling. I can see here, https://miningbusinessdata.com/different-types-api-ai-slot-filling-tasks/ that this is not a recommended way of solving your problem & this is because once you enter in webhook, you will have to write your own logic of NLP to handle user responses & understand the context of what user wants to say. So instead of having multiple prompts like `what type of vehicle->plane->we don't have this (enter car/truck)`, you can directly say `what type of vehicle (please enter any of this: car/truck)` so you don't have to define multiple prompts here & your work will be done. Unless you have car/truck in `user says` of your intent, it will continue promoting same question.